# Bound Listbox turns items invisible on data refresh. Why?

Tags: vb.net

I have a list box bound to a list is a class.  All works fine until I try to add a new item to the list. during this process the data source is set to nothing to refresh the list and apparently 'Refresh' doesn't do it.  The list gets refreshed and the other controls bound to the listboxes data show that the list is there and is correct however the list appears empty although it does show scroll bars.  I have tried to change the font color, just in case.. Nothing!

Does someone know why this happens? how to fix it? Or a better way to refresh?

Code:

```
Private Sub btnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click

    'lbNames is the listbox carrying all the data
    Dim oContacts As List(Of clsContact) = lbNames.DataSource
    lbNames.DataSource = Nothing

    'Build the new Item, add it to the collection
    Dim oNewCont As New clsContact
    oNewCont.Editable = True
    oNewCont.IsActive = True
    oNewCont.Firstname = "Jimmy"
    oNewCont.Lastname = "Smith"
    oContacts.Add(oNewCont)

    lbNames.Refresh()

    ' Re-Set up Autocomplete text box
    Dim MySource As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    For Each oc As clsContact In oContacts
        MySource.Add(oc.FullName)
    Next
    txtName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    txtName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource
    txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

    'Set List Box data back to the collection
    lbNames.DataSource = oContacts
    lbNames.DisplayMember = "FullName"

End Sub
```

The starting LOAD:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim oCont As List(Of clsContact)
    lbNames.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable

    Dim oTypes As List(Of clsPhoneType) = loadTypes()
    cboPhoneType.DataSource = oTypes
    cboPhoneType.DisplayMember = "Type"
    cboPhoneType.ValueMember = "ID"

    oCont = LoadNames()
    lbNames.DataSource = oCont
    lbNames.DisplayMember = "FullName"

    Dim MySource As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    For Each oc As clsContact In oCont
        MySource.Add(oc.FullName)
    Next
    txtName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    txtName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource
    txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
End Sub

Private Sub lbNames_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles lbNames.DrawItem

    e.DrawBackground()

    Dim textBrush As Brush = Brushes.Black
    Dim drawFont As System.Drawing.Font = e.Font

    If (e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.WhiteSmoke, e.Bounds)
    End If

    Dim oCont As clsContact = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.ListBox).Items(e.Index)
    If oCont.IsActive Then
        textBrush = Brushes.Black
        If oCont.IsDirty Then textBrush = Brushes.LightCoral
    Else
        textBrush = Brushes.LightGray
    End If

    Dim str = oCont.FullName
    e.Graphics.DrawString(str, e.Font, textBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault)
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: can you try to remove  lbNames.Refresh() ?

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: `oCont` only exists in FormLoad - make it a module level var

Comment: Looks like *something* is in your ListBox since the scrollbar is at the bottom.  Are there items visible if you scroll?  Post your draw code.  It looks like it should be OwnerDrawFixed.

Comment: saving the list via the DataSource does work (good catch @Lars), but seems a rather odd way to do it.  you might want to use OPTION STRICT - `Dim oContacts As List(Of clsContact) = lbNames.DataSource` is a cast and you might have others elsewhere which breaks it

Comment: The items are there if I click on them my textboxes etc react. I just cannot see them.

Comment: I don't think it is the drawing routine as then the form loads all is good.... All continues to be good until I add a new item to the list and set the data source to nothing and then back to the collection.

Comment: This can't be all of the code involved.  I see names in Green but no code that paints it green.  Make sure you check that e.Index > -1.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong tools. The [List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't raise any events whatsoever. When bound to a control, the control doesn't know if any items are added/removed/moved. Luckily, the [BindingList(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) comes to rescue. It will raise a [ListChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listchangedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event whenever the list is modified. As a bonus, if your class/model implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface, the control will also reflect property changes.

```
lbNames.DataSource = New BindingList(Of clsContact)(oCont)
```

Here's a sample form to show you the basics:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.btnAdd = New Button With {.TabIndex = 0, .Dock = DockStyle.Top, .Height = 30, .Text = "Add new contact"}
        Me.btnChange = New Button With {.TabIndex = 1, .Dock = DockStyle.Top, .Height = 30, .Text = "Change random contact name"}
        Me.lbContacts = New ListBox With {.TabIndex = 2, .Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
        Me.Controls.AddRange({Me.lbContacts, Me.btnChange, Me.btnAdd})
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleMeLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim list As New List(Of Contact)
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            list.Add(New Contact With {.Name = String.Format("Contact # {0}", i)})
        Next
        Me.lbContacts.DataSource = New BindingList(Of Contact)(list)
        Me.lbContacts.DisplayMember = "Name"
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleButtonAddClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim list As BindingList(Of Contact) = DirectCast(Me.lbContacts.DataSource, BindingList(Of Contact))
        list.Add(New Contact With {.Name = String.Format("Contact # {0}", (list.Count + 1))})
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleButtonChangeClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnChange.Click
        Static rnd As New Random()
        Dim list As BindingList(Of Contact) = DirectCast(Me.lbContacts.DataSource, BindingList(Of Contact))
        If (list.Count > 0) Then
            With list.Item(rnd.Next(0, list.Count))
                .Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            End With
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Class Contact
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
        Public Property Name As String
            Get
                Return Me.m_name
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                If (value <> Me.m_name) Then
                    Me.m_name = value
                    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"))
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_name As String
    End Class

    Private WithEvents btnAdd As Button
    Private WithEvents btnChange As Button
    Private WithEvents lbContacts As ListBox

End Class
```

Comment: The fact that the control doesn't know that items have need added or removed is the reason I remove the data source and reset it to the updated collection.  This doesn't really explain why the items can no longer be seen in the list after setting the data source.  The items are there as when I click around my textbox values change.  I just cant see them??!!

Comment: I can not answer *why* because I could not reproduce the problem with the given code. However, using a `BindingList<T>` or  `ObservableCollection<T>` is the preferred way of doing it. Did you check the `.Items` property to see if it contains any data?

Comment: All the data is intact even the newly added onject is in there. Its holding everything fine it just chooses to not show it to me!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution to fixing this problem is to flip the drawmode back to normal.
adding:
        lbNames.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal
        lbNames.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable
Fixes the problem.

I guess what is happening is that the drawing handler is becoming disconnected for some reason so the contests of the list are not redrawn when the data source is attached.

My new working code:
    Private Sub btnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click

```
    'lbNames is the listbox carrying all the data
    Dim oContacts As List(Of clsContact) = lbNames.DataSource
    lbNames.DataSource = Nothing

    'Build the new Item, add it to the collection
    Dim oNewCont As New clsContact
    oNewCont.Editable = True
    oNewCont.IsActive = True
    oNewCont.Firstname = "Jimmy"
    oNewCont.Lastname = "Smith"
    oContacts.Add(oNewCont)

    ' Re-Set up Autocomplete text box
    Dim MySource As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    For Each oc As clsContact In oContacts
        MySource.Add(oc.FullName)
    Next
    txtName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    txtName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource
    txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource

    'Set List Box data back to the collection
    lbNames.DataSource = oContacts
    lbNames.DisplayMember = "FullName"

    lbNames.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal
    lbNames.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable

End Sub
```